# How to recover a myopenid account not transferred before closing?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I had another account on StackExchange (with which I mostly participated on Programmers) which depended on myopenid.com. Having been absent for a while, I lost track of that account and myopenid closed in the meantime. I would be very sorry to lose it because I made some contributions with that account as well, and would like very much to keep it.

Is there any way to recover it or at least merge it with this one?

I would appreciate all comments and ideas you may have regarding this.

Comment: From Meta.StackExchange: [Missed the MyOpenID demise; account lost forever?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235192/missed-the-myopenid-demise-account-lost-forever) and [myOpenID shuts down February 1, 2014; add an alternative login method to your account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190442/213963).  It appears the thing to do is use the 'contact us' form.

Comment: @MichaelT - Thank you. I've contacted them as instructed (in one of those questions), and am waiting to see if I'll receive a reply.

Comment: @MichaelT - They replied and now we'll see if it is possible to recover the old account. Just wanted to thank you as well, for the advice.